# How do online calculators use AES-256 to do encryption since they are not interoperable?

Tags: c#-4.0, encryption, cryptography, aes

I would like use AES 256 with c#.  I find many example on the web with c# like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769741/Csharp-AES-bits-Encryption-Library-with-Salt).

And I found many example also with online tools like [this](http://myeasywww.appspot.com/utility/free/online/Crypt_Decrypt-MD5-AES-HMAC-SHA-DES-RABBIT/en?command=UTILITY&ID=2) or [this](http://uttool.com/encryption/aes/default.aspx) or [this](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/).  But when I try to encrypt with key from website on other website the decryption does not work and no encrypted key works with application.

I need an example how it works with online website or more explication.

Comment: I just tried AES encryption/decryption with your first online tool and it worked just fine. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: @demonplus That he thinks he can encrypt with the first site and decrypt with the second one

Comment: It sounds like you have some code which isn't working - you should show us that code...

Comment: @xanatos Initialization vector can be different for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various things that can be configured when you want to encrypt something. You clearly need to select an encryption algorithm (`AES`) and a key length (`256`).

Encryption algorithms work on binary data, so your password must be translated to binary data. The http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769741/Csharp-AES-bits-Encryption-Library-with-Salt uses an `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` to do it. Very good. It isn't clear how http://uttool.com/encryption/aes/default.aspx does it, and http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/ probably simply converts your password to UTF8 and enlarges it (padding with zero bytes) or cuts it (but it isn't really clear).

Then you have to select how multiple blocks of data are encrypted (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). The basic mode is ECB, where every block of data is encrypted in an independent way. It isn't very secure because two equal blocks of data will be encrypted in the same way resulting in the same encrypted data. An attacker will at least know that there is some data that is repeated. The codeproject example uses CBC, much more secure. The CBC encrypts a block based on the previous block, so that even if you repeat the same data, the encrypted data will be different. http://uttool.com/encryption/aes/default.aspx isn't clear what it does. http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/ lets you select the algorithm.

Some of these block cipher modes require an IV (Initialization Vector) to pre-initialize the block cipher mode. The codeproject example uses part of the binary data obtained by `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, while the http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/ gives you a predefined one based on the SHA1 of your password that you can then change.

Note that http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/ has a good explanation of all this.

Technically there is another "thing" that is normally set when you want to encrypt some data: padding. Block ciphers work only with some number of bytes at a time (AES with 16 bytes). If your data is shorter, you must "pad" it to 16 bytes. If your data is longer, you divide it in blocks of 16 bytes. You could still have a block smaller than 16 bytes (for example if you have 17 bytes, it is 16 + 1 bytes, so 16 + (1 + 15 padding) bytes. There are various ways to do this padding.

The point is: **unless you "align" all these fiddle things, you can't encrypt from one site and decrypt from another.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
If I understand the example on codeproject is correct and more secure. 
But If I explain to my my customer that I need use aes256 with key length:256 and CBC mode, 
it is possible with an encrypted key for an application to get the decryption in another application?
If it's too difficult with an other application, which algorithm encrypted is more easily?

Comment: @Zoners All the algorithms have these "fiddle" bits. Other things to set are padding, if there is a text password how it is converted to the binary password (encoding + binary conversion), how the IV is calculated (it can be randomly generated and prepended to the encrypted data, for example, or it can be calculated from the key as done in the codeproject sample, but this is less secure, because the IV would be reused, so that if you send twice the same text in two different days, the same encrypted stream is produced), and then you have to decide what you want to send... is it a file, or

Comment: ... or some binary data, or perhaps text? If it is text, then you have to decide the encoding (UTF8? UTF16? something else?)

Comment: I need a simple and efficient encryption to be used by the client and me.  Aes256 seems complicated , exist an other more easy?

Comment: @Zoners As I've said, all the real encryption algorithms have these fiddle bits. Real encryption is hard.

Comment: @Zoners If both of you are using C#, you can use the codeproject example code

Comment: I know from today that my client uses python